# CartThrob 'cart_items_info' in PHP

Tags: cartthrob

EE: 6.3.4

CartThrob: 6.3.0

I would like to get a user's current cart (the data that comes from the `cart_items_info` tag) using PHP.

I've been looking through the documentation and the database structure to find a way to do this, but I haven't had much luck.

Is there a PHP method or hook similar to the `cart_items_info` tag that I could use to get a users current cart items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at:

```
ee()->cartthrob->cart->items()
```

It's an array of the user's cart.

Also, if you're curious about how any of the template tags work, they're stored at `src/Tags`

Comment: Thanks! That works!